# Learn Python the Hard Way #48 — lexicon exercise

Tags: python, beginner, parsing, python-2.x

I'm trying to get some feedback on my code for the lexicon exercise (#48) in *Learn Python the Hard Way*. I have only recently started learning Python and want to make sure I have my fundamentals down before progressing. I have some experience coding (only with kdb+/q in my work environment) but none in Python, so all advice is welcomed.

```
verb=['go','kill','eat']
direction=['north','south','east','west']
noun=['bear','princess']
stop=['the','in','of']
vocab={'verb':verb,'direction':direction,'noun':noun,'stop':stop}

def scan(sentence):
    wordlist=sentence.split()
    result=[] #initialize an empty list
    for word in wordlist:
        found=False
        for key,value in vocab.items():
            if word.lower() in value:  #convert to lower case so that we can handle inputs with both cases
                result.append((key,word))
                found=True
                break
        if not found:
            try:
                word=int(word)
                result.append(('number',word))
            except ValueError:
                result.append(('error',word))
    return result
```

Python version 2.6.

Answer (score 10):

```
verb=['go','kill','eat']
direction=['north','south','east','west']
noun=['bear','princess']
stop=['the','in','of']
```

There is not a lot of point in storing these in separate variables only to stick them inside `vocab` just put the list literals inside `vocab`

```
vocab={'verb':verb,'direction':direction,'noun':noun,'stop':stop}
```

Python convention say to make constant ALL_CAPS. I'd also not abbreviate the names. Code is read more then written, so make it easy to read not to write.

```
def scan(sentence):
    wordlist=sentence.split()
    result=[] #initialize an empty list
```

Pointless comment. Assume you reader understand the language. You don't need to explain what [] means.

```
    for word in wordlist:
```

I'd use `for word in sentence.split():`

```
        found=False
```

Boolean logic flags are delayed gotos. Avoid them when you can

```
        for key,value in vocab.items():
            if word.lower() in value:  #convert to lower case so that we can handle inputs with both cases
```

Your dictionary is backwards. It maps from word types to lists of words. It'd make more sense to have a dictionary mapping from word to the word type.

```
                result.append((key,word))
                found=True
                break
        if not found:
```

Rather then this, use an `else` block on the for loop. It'll be execute if and only if no break is executed.

```
            try:
                word=int(word)
                result.append(('number',word))
```

Put this in the else block for the exception. Generally, try to have as little code in try blocks as possible. Also I wouldn't store the result in word again, I'd put in a new local.

```
            except ValueError:
                result.append(('error',word))

    return result
```

My approach:

```
WORD_TYPES = {
   'verb' : ['go', 'kill', 'eat'],
   'direction' : ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west'],
   'noun' : ['bear', 'princess'],
   'stop' : ['the','in','of']
}
# invert the dictionary
VOCABULARY = {word: word_type for word_type, words in WORD_TYPES.items() for word in words}

def scan(sentence):
    tokens = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        try:
            word_type = VOCABULAR[word]
        except KeyError:
            try:
                 value = int(word)
            except ValueError:
                 tokens.append( ('error',word) )
            else:
                 tokens.append( ('int', value) )
        else:
            tokens.append( (word_type, word) )
     return tokens
```

Alternately, using some regular expressions:

```
classifications = []
for word_type, words in WORD_TYPES.items():
    word_expression = '|'.join("(?:%s)" % re.escape(word) for word in words)
    expression = r"\b(?P<%s>%s)\b" % (word_type, word_expression)
    classifications.append(expression)
classifications.append(r"\b(?P<int>\d+)\b")
classifications.append(r"\b(?P<error>\w+)\b")
parser = re.compile('|'.join(classifications))

def scan(sentence):
    return [(match.lastgroup, match.group(0)) for match in parser.finditer(sentence)]
```

**EDIT**

If your version of python is to old to use the dict comphrensions you can use:

```
dict((word, word_type) for word_type, words in WORD_TYPES.items() for word in words)
```

Comment: thanks for the response! Very much appreciated. Would you mind walking me through the dictionary inversion? I was trying to drop it into my terminal and play with it but I get a SyntaxError:invalid syntax. It seemed to me to be some sort of variant on list comprehension where for each word in words (i.e. for each element in the value-pairs) it assigns the wordtype (i.e. the key in the original dictionary key-value pair) to that element. Not sure why it doesn't work though...

Comment: @JPC, which version of python are you running? The dict comprehension is a newer feature. But you've got the right idea of how it works. I'll add an alternate way

Comment: seem's I'm running on 2.6.4. Thanks! I appreciate it

Comment: @JPC, yeah I think you need 2.7 for the dict comp.